# Can't Use 'ŋ' In My LaTeX Document

Tags: unicode, characters, font-encodings

I am creating a textbook for a constructed language of mine. It's alphabet contains the letter 'ŋ', which LaTeX does not seem to like. For example:

```
\ae{}r\ng{} & past participle & He had eaten \\ \hline
```

Gives me this error:

```
Command \ng unavailable in encoding OT1. \r{u}\ng
```

I have UTF8 enabled:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The glyph corresponding to `\ng` is only available in T1 encoding: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: After doing this, I get this: http://pastebin.com/SgziCXij

Comment: Install a full TeX Live and then retry.

Comment: After installing the full TeX Live it worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “LATIN LETTER SMALL ENG” U+0148 character “ŋ” is available only in T1 encoded fonts. Unfortunately not all fonts available in TeX distributions have it: don't try it with `\usepackage{mathptmx}`, for instance.

Add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to your preamble (and upgrade your TeX distribution to a full one).

You can also profit from direct Unicode input, if you save your document as UTF-8:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\ae{}\r{u}\ng{} & past participle & He had eaten \\ \hline
æůŋ & past participle & He had eaten
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]